# Cache engine default is not properly configured

Tags: cakephp, caching

Error is:

```
 Error: [CacheException] Cache engine default is not properly configured.
```

Defaul cache engine is "File".

Please help.

**UPD**
CakePHP verison - 2.3.6
One of the Cache:config() calls:

```
Cache::config('default', array(
'engine' => $engine,
'duration' => '+1 week',
'probability' => 100,
'path' => CACHE . 'default' . DS,
'mask' => 0666,
'lock' => true
));
```

Comment: Why not posting the relevant part about your Cache::config() calls in your bootstrap or core file? Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: @mark $engine is File

Comment: Hm.. it's fixed. I just turn debug to 2, then back to 0 and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Setting debug to 2 invalidates the cached files. You can also delete them manually in app/tmp/cache/. Also, ensure that your app/tmp directory is writable recursively.

Comment: This answer should not have been down voted. It is correct. The default cache engine is file.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue; I found out that **php is not yet connected to redis**. So, you run

```
sudo apt-get install php5-redis
```

This will make connection between redis and php and make sure the default cache is configured.